# XSD link to XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I need to make a practice for my university. I need to use xml, xslt and xsd, but i'm having some trouble linking xsd to the xml file. Without the xsd file, everything works fine, but when i try to link the xsd file to my xml file it doesnt work.

Edit: This is the page without the XSD file: https://gyazo.com/6bda9a1e4a3dc9d270326a43d7b62215
and this is the page with the XSD file: https://gyazo.com/483f62775021ba6dea22b5046a4cffce

Here is my file nuevo.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="nuevo2.xsl"?>
<nuevo xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com nuevo.xsd">

<COCINA>
    <LIBRO TITULO="Cincuenta recetas fundamentales de la cocina canaria">
        <AUTORES>
            <AUTOR>
            Jose H. Chela
            </AUTOR>


            <AUTOR>
            Manuel Iglesias
            </AUTOR>

            <AUTOR>
            Jose Carlos Marrero
            </AUTOR>
        </AUTORES>
        <RECETA NOMBRE="Puchero canario">
            <TIPO> Primer plato </TIPO>
            <DESCRIPCION>
                El puchero canario, como la mayoría de los cocidos españoles, es, por sí mismo, un menú                     completo.
                Se trata de una de las ollas más completas de la culinaria nacional, sin duda, por su                       apabullante contenido de hortalizas y exóticos productos vegetales, aunque las fórmulas                     varían, claro está, en consonancia con los materiales de que disponga el cocinero o el ama de                       casa en cada momento.
                <image>
                    <img src="PUCHERO_CANARIO_NOT.jpg"/>
                </image>
            </DESCRIPCION>

            <INGREDIENTES ING= "carne de vacuno">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 500 gr</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="tocino">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 200 gr</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="chorizo">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 200 gr</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="costillas frescas o previamente desaladas">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 300 gr</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="muslos de pollo">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 3 piezas</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="garbanzos">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 2 tazas</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="piñas de millo">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 3 </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="habichuelas">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 100 gr</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="col">
                    <CANTIDAD>  - 1</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="zanahoras en lascas">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 2</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="calabaza">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 100 gr</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="bubangos">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 2</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="batatas">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 100 gr</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="papas">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 4 ó 5</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="peras del país">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 3</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="azafrán">
                    <CANTIDAD> (al gusto)</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="ajo">
                    <CANTIDAD> (al gusto)</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="sal">
                    <CANTIDAD> (al gusto)</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="cominos">
                    <CANTIDAD> (al gusto)</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="aceite">
                    <CANTIDAD> (al gusto)</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <ELABORACION>
                <PASO>
                    1. En un caldero grande con agua, en la que se habrá puesto un fisco -apenas nada- de                           aceite, se ponen, cuando pega a hervir, los trozos de carne con el chorizo y el                         tocino.
                </PASO>
            </ELABORACION>

            <ELABORACION>
                <PASO>
                    2. Media hora después, más o menos, echamos los garbanzos y los trozos de piña de                           millo. Cuando comprobemos que los garbanzos y la piña van enterneciéndose, sumamos al
                    conjunto las habichuelas, la col y las zanahorias. (Hay quien, en este momento, pone                            también, un ramito atado -para poder sacarlo luego- de especias: tomillo, laurel y                          hortelana; pero esto es opcional y va en gustos).
                </PASO>
            </ELABORACION>

            <ELABORACION>
                <PASO>
                    3. Han de pasar otros veinte minutos, al menos, antes de agregar la calabaza, el                            bubango y las peras. Y ya un poco después se añaden las batatas y las papas.
                </PASO>
            </ELABORACION>

            <ELABORACION>
                <PASO>
                    4. Unos minutos antes de retirar el puchero del fuego se aromatiza con un majado                            compuesto de azafrán, ajos y cominos. A esto se le llama “tiemplar” el puchero y es                             una operación que lo distingue también del resto de los cocidos españoles.
                </PASO>
            </ELABORACION>
        </RECETA>

        <RECETA NOMBRE="Escaldón">
            <TIPO> Segundo plato </TIPO>
            <DESCRIPCION>
                El escaldón es una antigua receta tradicional de la isla de Tenerife en donde su principal                      ingrediente es el característico gofio, uno de los productos más emblemáticos de la dieta de                        un canario, creado a base de cereales tostados y molidos. Es un plato que destaca por ser muy                       completo ya que a partir de unos ingredientes muy sencillos, conseguimos un gran aporte                     energético y de nutrientes para nuestro cuerpo.
                <image>
                    <img src="photo.jpg"/>
                </image>
            </DESCRIPCION>

            <INGREDIENTES ING= "gofio">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 500 gr</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="caldo de pescado o carne">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 1 litro</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="perejil">
                    <CANTIDAD> (al gusto)</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="ajo">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 2 dientes</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="pimienta dulce">
                    <CANTIDAD> (al gusto)</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="pimentón picante">
                    <CANTIDAD> (al gusto)</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="sal">
                    <CANTIDAD> (al gusto)</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <ELABORACION>
                <PASO>
                    1. Hervimos 1 litro de caldo de pescado o de carne en un caldero, preferimente casero                           para darle mucho más sabor.
                </PASO>
            </ELABORACION>

            <ELABORACION>
                <PASO>
                    2. Cuando el caldo esté hervido, lo retiramos y lo ponemos en un recipiente. Le                         añadimos el perejil y el gofio. Vamos echando poco a poco el gofio para mezclarlo                           todo bien y lo vamos sazonando a gusto.
                </PASO>
            </ELABORACION>

            <ELABORACION>
                <PASO>
                    3. Cuando la mezcla tenga buena consistencia, hacemos con ella una forma de rosquilla                           y lo ponemos en el recipiente dejado un hueco en el medio. A continuación, picamos                          los dientes de ajo y los sofreímos en aceite a fuego lento. Cuando esté dorado, le                          añadimos la pimienta dulce y el pimentón. Removemos bien y lo retiramos del fuego ya                            que si no, adquiere un sabor amargo.
                </PASO>
            </ELABORACION>

            <ELABORACION>
                <PASO>
                    4. Una vez tengamos listo el sofrito de ajos, lo vertemos en el hueco que hicimos en                            la masa de gofio. Podemos mezclarlo antes o ya en la mesa según el gusto de los                         comensales.
                </PASO>
            </ELABORACION>
        </RECETA>

        <RECETA NOMBRE="Truchas canarias">
            <TIPO> Tercer plato </TIPO>
            <DESCRIPCION>
                Las truchas o empanadillas dulces de batata es una receta típica de las Islas Canarias características para la época navideña ya que es un símbolo de familia y de nostalgia.
                <image>
                    <img src="Truchas-de-almendras-final.jpg"/>
                </image>
            </DESCRIPCION>

            <INGREDIENTES ING= "batata">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 1 kg</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="azúcar">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 100 gr</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="anís estrellado">
                    <CANTIDAD> (al gusto)</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="Marie Brizard">
                    <CANTIDAD> - una copa</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="almendras">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 200 gr</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="obleas">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 32 unidades</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="limón">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 1/2 </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="canela">
                    <CANTIDAD> (al gusto)</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="azúcar glas">
                    <CANTIDAD> (al gusto)</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="agua">
                    <CANTIDAD> - 1 litro</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="aceite ">
                    <CANTIDAD> (al gusto)</CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING="">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <INGREDIENTES ING=" ">
                    <CANTIDAD> </CANTIDAD>
            </INGREDIENTES>

            <ELABORACION>
                <PASO>
                    1. En un caldero metemos el agua e introducimos la batata cortada en pequeños trozos                            junto al anís estrellado y lo dejamos cocer.
                </PASO>
            </ELABORACION>

            <ELABORACION>
                <PASO>
                    2. Cuando la batata esté tierna, se escurre y se machacan junto con el azúcar, lo                           retiramos y lo dejamos repasar.
                </PASO>
            </ELABORACION>

            <ELABORACION>
                <PASO>
                    3. Calentamos un poco de aceite en una sartén y  doramos las almendras. Luego lo                            picamos y lo mezclamos bien junto con un poco de anís.
                </PASO>
            </ELABORACION>

            <ELABORACION>
                <PASO>
                    4. Se inorpora toda la pasta resultante de las  almendras a la batata, incorporando                             también la ralladura de limón y la canela. Y se mezcla ben.
                </PASO>
            </ELABORACION>

            <ELABORACION>
                <PASO>
                    5. Se va echando pequeñas porciones en las obleas y las cerramos en forma de                            empanadillas. Mientras tanto podemos ir calentando un poco de aceite. Cuando el                         aceite esté caliente, vamos dorando las empanadillas y las vamos echando en un plato                            con papel absorvente dejándolas reposar. Para finalizar echamos azúcar glas a gusto                             por encima.
                </PASO>
            </ELABORACION>
        </RECETA>
    </LIBRO>
</COCINA>
</nuevo>
```

nuevo2.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="/">

<HTML>
    <BODY>
            <tr bgcolor="#F4F6F7">
        <B><H1 align="center"> Tres recetas fundamentales de la cocina canaria</H1> </B>
        <BR/>
        <BR/>
        <TABLE>
            <xsl:for-each select="COCINA/LIBRO/RECETA">
            <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="@NOMBRE"/>
            <TR>
            <TD>
            <B>
            <h2 align="center"><xsl:value-of select="@NOMBRE"/></h2>
            </B>
            <div align="justify"><xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPCION"/></div>
            <BR/><BR/>
                        <div style="float: left;">
                            <img>
                            <xsl:attribute name="width">
                            865
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="height">
                            478
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="border">
                            2px
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                            <xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPCION/image/img/@src"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            </img>
                    </div>
                    <div align="center">
                <B> Ingredientes: </B>
                <BR/>
                <xsl:for-each select="INGREDIENTES">
                <TR>
                <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="@ING"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="CANTIDAD"/>
                <BR/>
                </TD>
                </TR>
                </xsl:for-each>
                    </div>
                    <div align="justify">
                    <BR/>
                    <B> Pasos: </B>
                    <BR/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ELABORACION">
                        <BR/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="PASO"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    </div>
            </TD>
            </TR>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </TABLE>

        <B> Autores: </B>
            <BR/>
            <xsl:for-each select="COCINA/LIBRO/AUTORES">
                <xsl:value-of select="AUTOR"/>
                <BR/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and nuevo.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com nuevo.xsd">
<xs:element name="nuevo">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>x
    <xs:element name="COCINA">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="LIBRO">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="AUTORES">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="AUTOR" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="RECETA" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="TIPO"/>
                      <xs:element name="DESCRIPCION">
                        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                          <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="image">
                              <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                  <xs:element name="img">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                      <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                          <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="src" use="optional"/>
                                        </xs:extension>
                                      </xs:simpleContent>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                  </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                              </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                          </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
                      <xs:element name="INGREDIENTES">
                        <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CANTIDAD"/>
                          </xs:sequence>
                          <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="ING" use="optional"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
                      <xs:element name="ELABORACION">
                        <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="PASO"/>
                          </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:choice>
                    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="NOMBRE" use="optional"/>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="TITULO"/>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: What doesn't work, the XSLT code? If you use a namespace (i.e. `xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"`) in the XML document then you need to adapt your XSLT code, with XSLT `version="2.0"` and an XSLT 2 processor the easiest way is changing it to `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="https://www.w3schools.com">`. This has nothing to do with schemas and schemas can be used for defining XML documents without a namespace.

Comment: When i try the code only with de XML and XSLT files it works, but when i link the XSD file with the XML file, it doenst works.                                            This is the page without the XSD file : https://gyazo.com/6bda9a1e4a3dc9d270326a43d7b62215                                     and this is the page with the XSD file :https://gyazo.com/483f62775021ba6dea22b5046a4cffce

Comment: Where in the server is nuevo.xsd? is it accessible to the page generator code? Also, do you get any error on server side?